# VueJS and Drop down values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Am I grabbing the value of the selection incorrectly in this Vue template form?

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="object.property">
        <option selected="selected" value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the value of `object.property` to the select element correctly.

But, Vue is going to ignore the `selected` attribute on the first option element.

Here's the warning you will get if you try to use this template:

> inline selected attributes on `<option>` will be ignored when using v-model. Declare initial values in the component's data option instead.

So, if you want the initial value of the select to be the first option, set `object.property` to that value when you define it in the `data` method.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { object: { property: "Option 1" } } 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select class="form-control" v-model="object.property">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  
  {{ object.property }}
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason every time I pass the object in to the patch request it gets put as null and I don't know why.

Comment: What patch request?